# How to set globally the URL fetching timeout?

Tags: google-app-engine, timeout, jax-rs, urlfetch

I'm developing an application running on App Engine. One of my Task calls a web service. To do that I use JAX-RS. However, one of the call reachs the time out set by app engine (5 secondes). I'd like to increase this timeout to 10s but I'm not able to modify it. Indeed, JAX-RS doesn't allow to catch the HttpConnection Object created.

My question is : is it possible to configure globally the time out of URL Fetching?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which JAX-RS stack you use, but for Jersey you can do:

---

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
```

---

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_THREADPOOL_SIZE,10);
Client client = Client.create(cc);
client.setConnectTimeout(1000);
client.setReadTimeout(15000);
```

---

It is important to note that creating a Jersey client on GAE is relatively slow, so you might want to make this client a static variable within the instance. (It is a thread-safe object, so no problems there) Still this can add 2-5 seconds to the spin-up of your instance.